# Origination of internal forces in a beam under axial loads

Tags: solid-state-physics, potential-energy, free-body-diagram, equilibrium, statics

Take a prismatic beam and subject it to a tensile loading, assume we are applying a load of **10 N** on both of its ends. As we know, the beam stretches by a certain amount on either sides.

And since **atoms of a cross section** which are at the extremes of the beam experiences the most displacement from their mean positions, therefore they store more potential energy resulting in **greater restoring force** to get to their equilibrium position. In other words, the displacement of the atoms of the cross section from their mean position increases as we move from the center of the beam, i.e., The atoms which are present in the central cross section of the beam experiences no displacement from their mean position.

[image]

This also implies that the **restoring force of a cross section** (which tries to bring back the atoms to their equilibrium position) also varies directly proportional to the distance from the center of the beam.

[image]

So if we take a section of the beam at the middle, there will be **no restoring force** acting on that cross section since that cross section has never displaced from its mean position. But from the free body diagram we do see that there **must be a restoring force** which must be equal to **10 N** acting on that cross section. Can someone clarify on this discrepancy

***I really want to understand how does restoring forces originate at an atomic level in an elastic material when the material is stretched or compressed, and how does that restoring force remain constant for each and every cross section of the material***

Comment: You insist that the atoms cannot be displaced, yet you use the phrase “mean position.” Do you see the problem here?

Comment: @Matt Hanson Ah, I don't seem to get it, could you please elaborate. If the term "mean position" is incorrect can I say atoms in the solid are at rest since the intermolecular bonds are strong compared to fluids, therefore the atoms cannot move easily and so they remain in the same position.

Comment: Your assumptions that atoms cannot move is flat out incorrect. It is better to say that they vibrate about their energetic minima. In the case of your stress your have applied to the material, you are essentially forcing the atoms to adopt positions closer than their ideal, which increases the energy of the system. When you release whatever deformed the system, it will “snap back.” Now, you can deform the system so badly it cannot undo what you have done, but that is not the case here. That is why I object to your concept that atoms are frozen in a solid lattice. They aren’t!

Comment: Yes, I got your point. But however the atoms on the extremes have more potential energy (means more vibration) compared to the ones in the middle right? which means that they exert more restoring force to come to equilibrium compared to the ones in the middle, but the free body diagram doesn't say so, i.e., it implies every cross section exerts the same restoring force.

Comment: I will counter with this: how many atoms are in this “extreme” situation you describe? Is it 5 layers deep? Let’s call it 500. Who cares! There are uncountable numbers of layers of these atoms in a large beam, so the edge case is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: I still don't get it, could you theorise on how do restoring forces develop in a beam which is under axial load and could you explain how does that restoring force remain the same on all the cross sections of the beam

Comment: I have no idea exactly how it happens. I do know that you are forcing atoms closer together by definition because the beam was COMPRESSED. The natural way to relieve that stress is to allow the atoms to relax back to their original inter nuclear separations, which are presumably vibrating about the equilibrium separation. The lattice is not some inflexible thing, but something that is stable and requires energy to modify. I’m not sure what more you want here.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, however the beam was in its unstretched normal state (not compressed), then I apply a tensile load of 10N on both ends which elongates the beam, this is the scenario. I just want to know how does restoring force develop within a material when stretched eg:Spring

Comment: Ok, so the opposite of what I said.. stretched or compressed is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply the axial load on the object, it spreads quite uniformly across the length of the object.  You aren't actually just pulling the ends far away from the middle of the object.  You are pulling each part of the object further away from the parts connected to it.

For simplicity, let's say your bar is 1 atom thick, and 9 atoms wide.  When you apply the axial load, the middle atom (5) has the atoms beside it moving further away, the same thing that happens between atoms 1 and 2 at the edge.  The attraction between the atoms wants them to go back to the original spacing, so the elastic force tries to bring 4-5-6 closer together the same way it does 1-2.

So it really only makes sense to think of the total elongation of the object, because *any* two points are getting further apart when you stretch it, the middle stretches just as much as the ends.

In your example you could consider either end as the part that doesn't move, while the middle and other end get further from the end that doesn't move.  It works out the same.  Your reference point is arbitrary, so it makes sense that it's really each part of the bar getting further from adjacent parts, independant of what part you consider stationary.

Comment: Thanks very much for the elaboration. Definitely makes sense to me, all along I was just focusing on one reference point which was the middle of the beam here. Could you tell me how does the restoring force form in the atomic level. As we know as the beam is stretched electrons tend to move further away from the nucleus causing its potential energy to increase, if what stated here is true how does the force get generated on the electron to go back to its equilibrium position, is it due to the electrostatic force by the nucleus.

Comment: Or if all this is wrong could you tell me the theory on how restoring forces are generated on the atomic level

Comment: @JeffyJames TBH most of what I know comes from an engineering background where the "why" was never really explained in depth.  My very basic understanding is that the atoms are arranged in their preferred way under no load, and the applied forces can shift that arrangement, but assuming you dont exceed some threshold (which depends on the material), when the force goes away the intermolecular forces take everything back to the preferred arrangement.